# How to read CSV like datastructures in JSON with ExtJS4 stores?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

The normal JSON approach looks something like this:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "header1": "some value",
      "header2": "some other value"
    },
    {
      "header1": "some value",
      "header2": "some other value"
    },
    {
      "header1": "some value",
      "header2": "some other value"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

But when I use this, there is a major overhead, because of all the "header1" and "header2" stuff.

So I thought about a more CSV like approach:

```
{
  "headers": [ "header1", "header2" ],
  "list": [
    [ "some value", "some other value" ],
    [ "some value", "some other value" ],
    [ "some value", "some other value" ],
    ...
  ]
}
```

but the ExtJS4 stores are more fond of the first style. Is there an easy possibility to use the second format or should I convert it on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using Ext.data.Store with an array reader and ajax proxy.  You do not need any headers on the server side, you should just define what your headers are going to be in the model on the client side.  So for an example, you could use code like this on the client side:

```
Ext.define("MyModel", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    fields: [
        {name: "header1"},
        {name: "header2"}
    ]
});
var theProxy = new Ext.data.proxy.Ajax({
    timeout: 120000,
    method:  "POST",
    url:     "your_url_here",
        reader:  new Ext.data.reader.Array({
            root:          "list"
        })
});
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    proxy:      theProxy,
    model:      "MyModel"
});
```

Make sure when you define the model that the fields are in the same order as the array returned from the server.
And this would be what is returned by the server:

```
{
  "list": [
    [ "some value", "some other value" ],
    [ "some value", "some other value" ],
    [ "some value", "some other value" ],
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to convert it, but there are other ways to reduce the overhead, like the mapping attribute on a field, so you can actualy send just one letter to identify the attribute like :

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "1": "some value",
      "2": "some other value"
    },
    {
      "1": "some value",
      "2": "some other value"
    },
    {
      "1": "some value",
      "2": "some other value"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

and the fields:

```
{name: 'header1', type:'string', mapping:'1'}
{name: 'header2', type:'string', mapping:'2'}
```

It's just a suggestion but this will reduce the overhead.

Comment: would this work with an array too? I mean `obj[0]` for `{ 0: "val"}` and `array[0]` for `["val"]` are both permitted ways to access stuff in javascript.

Comment: Maybe i don't quite understand the question but if you have something like "header1":[some array], the array will be contained inside the header1 field in the store and can be accessed by get('header1')[0]..

Comment: you wrote, I should make something like this: `{ "0": "val", "1": "val" }` and I wanted to know if it was equivalent to `["val", "val"]`.

Comment: i think we have a missunderstanding :),you said that header1 and header2 created major overhead, so i assume you have a big list. So my solution was to keep the first json style but replace the two words with just one letter since it doesn't change. This will reduce the overhead and help you by using the stores json proxy to load the data. Sending it as an array and then processing it to be added to the store will be even more time consuming if you are dealing with a large amount of data. So if you can chose the way to send your data, use the exjs stores format, it will make your life easier:)

Comment: I see. I assumed, that access to an object with nummeric index is the same in javascript as with arrays. Which gave me the conclusion, that ExtJS would take both.